# Pandas ExcelWriter(...,engine='odf') - no module named odf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ods

I'm confused as to why I'm unable to save my data to a .ods document, with the provided error. I've looked at the documentation for `pandas.ExcelWriter()` and it clearly states to use `engine='odf'` to be able to save as a `.ods`.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

... # nothing of value

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=COLS, index=None)
with pd.ExcelWriter('new.ods', engine="odf") as doc:
    df.to_excel(doc, sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

Error:

```
File "..../main.py", line 190, in <module>
    with pd.ExcelWriter('new.ods', engine="odf") as doc:
File "..../Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_odswriter.py", line 34, in __init__
    from odf.opendocument import OpenDocumentSpreadsheet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odf'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing odfpy

```
pip install odfpy
```

https://pypi.org/project/odfpy/

Comment: Thanks Navyad . I'm surprised the documentation didn't mention this requirement. Google wasn't much help either. I never would have known about that.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @navyad

```
!pip install odfpy
```

Also, make sure you **do not** write `engine='odfpy'` instead of `engine='odf'`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=COLS, index=None)
with pd.ExcelWriter('new.ods', engine="odf") as doc:
    df.to_excel(doc, sheet_name="Sheet1")
```