# Python pathlib not accepted by Pandas.ExcelWriter(..)

Tags: python, pandas, pathlib

After [finally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70210144/pandas-excelwriter-engine-odf-no-module-named-odf) getting Pandas to output my file as a spreadsheet (silly issue), I ran into an issue with the file path input not being read properly, even as a raw string. Eventually I stumbled upon the `pathlib` library, and it's been successful in allowing me to read and write to my file as needed. However, now I'm back to `ExcelWriter` complaining about my file again.

Here's my ugly attempt at using `pathlib` to create the paths (directories substituted):

```
import pandas as pd
core = input("Core number ('core_#k'): ")
part = input("Part name ('part_#'): ")

file_level = 'core_' + core + 'k'
in_file_name =  file_level + '_part_' + part + '.txt'
out = in_file_name[:-4] + '.ods'

# format filenames
path_raw = Path("DRIVELABEL:\someDirectories\\")

raw_text_path = Path(path_raw) / "raw_text" / file_level / in_file_name

spreadsheet_path = Path(path_raw) / "spreadsheets" / file_level / out
```

Error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DRIVELABEL:/SomeDirectories/outputFile.ods'`

I can't figure out how to get `ExcelWriter` to write this file properly. The only thing I can think right now is that the `file_level` for `spreadsheet_path` doesn't exist yet, but shouldn't it be created at write?

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(spreadsheet_path.as_posix(), engine='odf') as doc:
    df.to_excel(doc, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)
```

Comment: You can combine `pathlib.Path` by `path_raw = Path("my_path"); path_full  = path_raw / "directory"` instead of combining them with `\\`. You can also try to pass the pandas Writer the `Path().as_posix()` and see if that works.

Comment: Also please try to give a minimal working example or reduce the paths length to what is necessary. That makes it easier to read and potentially to reproduce and give a suggestion on how to fix it.

Comment: `Path(in_path_raw + '\\' + file_level + '\\' + in_file_name)` **no**. This misses the *whole point* of `Path` objects, that you shouldn't be constructing the path's manually. Use `Path(in_path_raw ) / file_level / in_file_name`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, that really helped clean up the code. And thanks @PythonF, the `as_posix()` removed the \\ error, however I'm still getting "No such file or directory" when writing out. Updating to reflect.

Comment: Ended up manually creating the output directories, all is well.